# how to go up one level to get the path url in html?

Tags: css

How to access images that are one folder above. The background-image does not appear in the html because of wrong directory or reference.

```
background-image:url("imgs/hours.png");
        #schedules{
            float: left;
            margin-left:10%;
            background-image: url(file:///C|/wamp/www/web/crosscafe/imgs/hours.png);
        }
        span {
            font-weight:bold;
        }
```

Comment: are you loading the html file from an http url, or file:///? you can't load local content via file: if the containing page was loaded from http://

Comment: does a root-relative path work - `/imgs/hours.png` or `/crosscafe/imgs/hours.png`, depending what the website points at?

Comment: and which path is your CSS?? ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said before, and just to make sure, if you're using WAMP you need to access the webpage through the `localhost` or any address that was provided for that purpose. Accessing through `file://` normally ignores most of the server-side usage WAMP provides you with.

That being said, I think your problem is fairly simple. If you are using a framework file structure you probably have the following strcture:

- imgs/
- css/
- js/
- index.html

So, and since you're working on your CSS which is in the `css` subfolder, your URL needs to be the following:

`background-image:url("../imgs/hours.png");`

The two points (`../`) tell the browser to go to the parent folder, then into the `imgs` folder and then search for `hours.png`.

Comment: thanks i could access images in my html by imgs/hours.png and i copied that though ignoring that my css is one folder down and i need to go up thanks.:)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should only comment css using `/*` and `*/`. `//` in css will not be treated as comment at all.

For your problem, you should use firebug to make sure that your element which id is `schedules` have a appropriate height and width.

And, if you are using WAMP, access your website from a URL start with `http://`, that page could not display a image stored on your local side, I mean, via `file://`. This is prohibited by your broswer. You should use the relative path instead, and the relative path is start from your css file.

So you can try this:

```
#schedules{
    float: left;
    margin-left:10%;
    background-image: url(imgs/hours.png);
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

and save "imgs" near your css file.

If you still have problems, I think you should paste your HTML on.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to display an image from that imgs directory in other place in your website, does it is shows? If not, it can be your  .htaccess file. It might be blocking the access to your images dir.